# NaN in Eigen's BDCSVD

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, svd

I am using Eigen in my C++ Programm for efficient Tensor-Storage and came around an error.

If I use the BDCSVD-Module to calculate an (quite simple) Singular value Decomposition, everything breaks down. 
The Error comes up, as I try to calculate

```
int n = 512;
Eigen::MatrixXd A = n * Eigen::MatrixXd::Ones(n, n);
Eigen::BDCSVD<Eigen::MatrixXd> SVD(A, Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV);
```

This should give me Singular Values and thin U and V-Matrices. Since the Matrix consists of a large bunch of 512, the matrix has only rank 1. 
The JacobiSVD-Module gives correct results, BDCSVD gives me a bunch of nan-Values.  Where do they come from?

I use Visual Studio 15 in Version 14.0.25431.01 and have set up everything according to [Eigen IDE-Page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=IDEs#Visual_Studio), this happens in Debug or Release Mode, 32bit or 64bit.

In more "random"-examples of a similar size, BCD outperforms Jacobi by a factor of 30 or more, so I really would like to use BCD.

Comment: The Eigen manual (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1BDCSVD.html) explicitly states that "...this algorithm is unlikely to provide accurate result when compiled with unsafe math optimizations. For instance, this concerns Intel's compiler (ICC), which perfroms such optimization by default unless you compile with the -fp-model precise option. Likewise, the -ffast-math option of GCC or clang will significantly degrade the accuracy." Maybe this was the source of your problem, although if you get the error in Debug Mode something else might be responsible.

Answer (score 0):

A number of if bug fixes have gone into this implementation in recent years. Please give it another try with the current version at https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen. A number of these fixes are also available in the 3.4 release https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/releases/3.4.0.